# Atmega8535 INT0 INT1 INT2 INT3

Tags: assembly, external, avr, interrupt, atmega

I am using Atmega8535 microcontoller and STK200 development board, I am trying to use more than one external interrupt, but for some reason only INT0 works and others do nothing, here is the related code:

```
;Interrupt Vector Addresses 
.equ     INT0addr=$001            ;External Interrupt0 Vector Address 
.equ     INT1addr=$002
.equ     INT2addr=$003
.equ     INT3addr=$004
.equ     INT4addr=$005

//interrupts
.org     INT0addr 
         rjmp   INT0              ;External Interrupt0 Vector 
.org     $0015                    ;Program address 

.org     INT1addr 
         rjmp   INT1              ;External Interrupt1 Vector 
.org     $0015                    ;Program address

.org     INT2addr 
         rjmp   INT2              ;External Interrupt0 Vector 
.org     $0017

.org     INT3addr 
         rjmp   INT3              ;External Interrupt0 Vector 
.org     $0018

.org     INT4addr 
         rjmp   INT4              ;External Interrupt0 Vector 
.org     $0019
;External Interrupt0 Service Routine 
INT0:    cli                      ;Prevent any more interrupts while ISR is running

     rjmp reset 
     reti                     ;Return and enable interrupts again

;External Interrupt1 Service Routine 
INT1:    cli                      ;Prevent any more interrupts while ISR is running

         rjmp reset 
         reti                     ;Return and enable interrupts again
;External Interrupt1 Service Routine 
INT2:    cli                      ;Prevent any more interrupts while ISR is running

         rjmp reset 
         reti                     ;Return and enable interrupts again
;External Interrupt1 Service Routine 
INT3:    cli                      ;Prevent any more interrupts while ISR is running

         rjmp reset 
         reti                     ;Return and enable interrupts again
;External Interrupt1 Service Routine 
INT4:    cli                      ;Prevent any more interrupts while ISR is running

         rjmp reset 
         reti                     ;Return and enable interrupts again
```

Comment: Please post `reset` and explain what the desired behavior is and what the the current behavior is.

Answer (score 0):

You might be asking a bit too much from this processor. According to the [processor reference](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2502.pdf) (pg. 65) this processor only has 3 external interrupts INT0, INT1 and INT2 (on PORTD.2, PORTD.3 and PORTB.2 respectively) ... also worth reading pg 68ff!

I don't see that you initially set the Global Interrupt Enable bit (bit 7 of SREG) which after Reset is 0 and preventing any interrupts from being processed, and also the individual interrupts must be enabled (register GICR)

You have a lot of superfluous `.org` in your code (e.g. lines 11, 13).

I recommend you include the device specific inc file, and - for the sake of clarity -  specify the full interrupt vector table e.g.

```
.nolist
.include <m8535def.inc>
.list

.org 0x0000
                     ; .... highest priority
    jmp V_RESET      ; Reset
    jmp V_ExtINT0    ; External Interrupt 0
    jmp V_ExtINT1    ; External Interrupt 1
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter2 Compare Match
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter2 Overflow
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter1 Capture Event
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter1 Compare Match A
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter1 Overflow
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Timer/Counter0 Overflow
    jmp V_NOINT      ; SPI Serial Transfer Complete
    jmp V_NOINT      ; USART, RX Complete
    jmp V_NOINT      ; USART Data Register Empty
    jmp V_NOINT      ; USART, TX Complete
    jmp V_NOINT      ; ADC Conversion Complete
    jmp V_NOINT      ; EEPROM Ready
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Analog Comparator
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Two-wire Serial Interface
    jmp V_ExtINT2    ; External Interrupt Request 2
    jmp V_NOINT      ; TimerCounter0 Compare Match
    jmp V_NOINT      ; Store Program Memory Read
                     ; .... lowest priority

V_RESET:
    ; define stack pointer
    ; set individual interrupt bits
    ; initialize ports, etc.

    sei              ; enable general interrupts

MAIN:
    rjmp MAIN

V_ExtINT0:
    ; INT0 handler
    reti

V_ExtINT1:
    ; INT1 handler
    reti

V_ExtINT2:
    ; INT2 handler
    reti

V_NOINT:
    ; e.g. flash a LED otherwise unused to show abnormal condition
    reti
```